# SQL Server Query to MS Access Query

Tags: delphi

Hi Friend I have a query in SQL Server want to be run in MS Access any one to help me to convert to MS Access SQL query?

```
update stock
set qty = qty - TotalQty
from (
select Sales_Detial.barcode, sum(Sales_Detial.qty) as TotalQty
from Sales_Detial
group by Sales_Detial.barcode
) as a
where a.barcode = stock.barcode
```

Comment: Please add a description of what does not work and where you have problems.

Comment: Why is that a Delphi question? It is about pure ```SQL```!